# A comprehensive regex for key word validation

Tags: regex

How to write a regex for key word validation having following constraints

1. All alphabets and digits are allowed.
2. You can use a blank space with in a keyword, but leading or tailing spaces are not allowed.
3. When using the hyphen character '-' it can only be used to hyphenate words and cannot have blank space around it.

**For Example**

"kkda asdlkfj-kklda12" should match

"kdka - klad lakdjoa" should not match

" kdakla120alsd  " should not match(space at start and end)

Comment: What flavor of regex do you require?

Comment: @MichaelBeer simple one, which can be used in Java application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pattern:

```
^(?:[a-z0-9]+(?: (?!$)|-|$))+$
```

- `^` Beginning of line.
- `(?:` Non capturing group.
- `[a-z0-9]+` Match alphanumeric values.
- `(?: (?!$)|-|$))` Non capturing group for either whitespace (as long as it does not precede end of string `(?!$)`), a `-` character or end of string.
- `)` Close non capturing group.
- `+` Repeat non capturing group.
- `$` Assert position end of line.

You can try it live [here](https://regex101.com/r/AZqi9u/4).